# How do I make microtonal music less jarring?

Tags: chord-theory, composition, microtonality

I'm a beginner at composing with microtones. I understand that microtonal music is going to be jarring for most people because it is so different compared to 12-tet music. My current strategy is to kind of sneak the microtones in in the inner voices of chords. I also use "shimmer" effects similar to those in [this piece](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6I9oKGIWmZI) by using downminor 2nd intervals (I am currently using 24-tet). Essentially, my strategy of making microtonal music less jarring is to write as if I am in 12-tet and use microtones as "color".

What other ideas and strategies can be used to accomplish this goal?

Edit: An example of a "non-jarring" use of microtones (for me at least) is the [transition into G half sharp minor in Little Blue by Jacob Collier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUGoUHKAGAE).

Comment: If you don't want your music to sound like you're using microtones, why are you using microtones?

Comment: I think you'll get better answers to this question in [The Auditorium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium). You can post a recording of one of your pieces and ask for feedback, which is the main purpose of that chat room.

Comment: BTW, there are a number of microtonal compositions already posted there by another user. Those might provide some insights into the kind of effects you're going for.

Comment: "I understand that microtonal music is going to be jarring for most people because it is so different compared to 12-tet music": not necessarily.  It might just sound like a period instrument group playing baroque music, or like a barbershop quartet.  @AlexanderWoo lol!  "My current strategy is to kind of sneak the microtones in in the inner voices of chords": this may give unsophisticated listeners the impression that the performance is out of tune.  It may be better to be up front about the tone pallette than to try to be sneaky.

Comment: I think the "jarring" idea needs to be examined a bit. What about Arabic music. I understand some of that music used scales with microtones. Do you rate that as jarring? Some do. Personally, I don't.

Comment: An example of a "non-jarring" use of microtones (for me at least) is the transition into G half sharp minor in Little Blue by Jacob Collier. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUGoUHKAGAE I'll add this to the question.

Comment: ... I'd also think that microtones in diminished chords could seem very reasonable... And, even in very classical jazz-ish stuff, like "close 4" and so on, those diminished chords do not seem wildly out-of-key, to begin with.

Comment: Aren't blue notes a type of microtone? That could be another approach. Not necessarily blues, but perhaps a select palette, very limited, of certain microtonal chords.

Comment: Too bad your question was closed. It was interesting, and answerable. Consider looking in Stockhausen and pointillism and how factors other than vertical harmony can make music "jarring" and disjunct. Then assess microtonal works through that framework asking whether the composer is using elements beside vertical microtonal chords to create jarring effects.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_nQgNKSl5Y has moments of kooky, disjunct effect, but others somewhat serene. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq9-6NnXPVg while it surely has a strange, other-worldly sound, and is sometimes jarring, notice the many passages with slow, even rhythms, and the smooth lines, and how that contributes to the overall effect. Don't necessarily equate dissonance with "unpleasant" and use your other musical resources to create less jarring effects... whatever exactly that means to you.

Comment: You might also draw inspiration from Debussy. While he didn't use microtones, he did use "traditional" dissonances - tritones, cluster-like seconds, whole tone scales, etc. - but used those harmonic materials to make lush, beautiful music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion is working with either of:

- A tuning that is not an equal temperament;
- An equal temperament other than 24-TET (a.k.a. 24EDO).  24-TET just sticks a set of 12 "out-of-tune" pitches between the familiar 12, so of course it seems jarring.

Maybe choose an EDO where some of the intervals align well with the just versions of some diatonic intervals from common-practice music.  In some cases they will align *better* with just intervals than 12-EDO, while allowing some modulation that you wouldn't get with just intonation, or well temperaments.

I would also say that once you choose an EDO, start with the melody.  Choose a subset of the EDO for most of your melody notes just as common practice music selects mostly from 7 of the 12 tones, with some extras added for modulation, color, etc.

Try selecting a subset whose size is coprime with the size of the EDO.  (Consider that 5 and 7 are both coprime with 12, and that scales of size 5 and 7 are common).  It's no coincidence that the fifth interval in 12EDO corresponds to 7/12 of an octave and it can be used to generate a diatonic scale. (As can 5/12, which corresponds to the fourth.)

Then experiment with harmonies to suit your own idea of what is and is not "jarring" in the setting.  (I personally find those "shimmer" effects to be jarring so obviously it's a matter of taste and cultural conditioning.)

The [Xenharmonic wiki page on EDOs](https://en.xen.wiki/w/EDO#How_do_I_explore_so_many.3F) also gives some ideas of how to choose.